# How do I fix IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I know this has been asked before but I'm not sure why my resources are turning null they have been added to the build path correctly. Also the images display so they're being read but for some reason I'm getting this.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at game.model.image.BufferedImageLoader.loadImage(BufferedImageLoader.java:14)
at game.model.gfx.ImageManager.<init>(ImageManager.java:22)
at game.model.ui.Menu.<init>(Menu.java:26)
at game.Game.<init>(Game.java:49)
at game.Game.main(Game.java:173)
```

First line is pointing to this

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
```

In this class.

```
public class BufferedImageLoader {

private BufferedImage image;

public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
}
```

And this is how I'm using the images.

```
public class ImageManager {

public BufferedImage mainMenu, play, playh, menu, menuh,
exit, exith, help, helph, banner;

public ImageManager() {
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    try {
        banner = loader.loadImage("/images/banner.png");
        mainMenu = loader.loadImage("/images/menubg.png");
        play = loader.loadImage("/images/play.png");
        playh = loader.loadImage("/images/playh.png");
        help = loader.loadImage("/images/help.png");
        helph = loader.loadImage("/images/helph.png");
        exit = loader.loadImage("/images/exit.png");
        exith = loader.loadImage("/images/exith.png");
        menu = loader.loadImage("/images/menu.png");
        menuh = loader.loadImage("/images/menuh.png");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And lastly this is how I actually display the images.

```
            //main menu background
        g2d.drawImage(im.mainMenu, 0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT- 40, null);

        //banner on main menu
        g.drawImage(im.banner, 65, 30, 478, 73, null);

        //play button on main menu
        g.drawImage(im.play, 70, 150, 200, 64, null);

        //help button on main menu
        g.drawImage(im.help, 70, 250, 200, 64, null);

        //exit button on main menu
        g.drawImage(im.exit, 70, 350, 200, 64, null);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your images stored in a package called "images"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should want to learn how to interpret the stacktrace of an exception:

- javax.imageio.ImageIO.read reported a problem, it received a null input
- BufferedImageLoader created that input variable from the expression `getClass().getResource(path)`. Therefore a path string could not be translated into a valid resource URL
- ImageManager line 22 passed a path variable which in the end could not be turned into a real resource.

Therefore it is a good idea to visit line 22 of your ImageManager class, and check if the referenced image file really exists.